# Logs not appearing in Web Inspector

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, trigger.io, web-inspector

Both `ForgeLog`s and `NSLog`s aren't showing up in my Safari Web Inspector when I'm testing. Am I doing something wrong or is that intentional?

```
[ForgeLog d:@"Playing file at..."];
```

EDIT: Here's the rest of the code for context. (This time using `NSLog`.)

```
#import "audio_API.h"

static AVAudioPlayer* player = nil;

@implementation audio_API


+ (void)play:(ForgeTask*)task {

    // parse the file url from the file object
    ForgeFile* file = [[ForgeFile alloc] initWithFile:[task.params objectForKey:@"file"]];
    NSString* fileURL = [file url];

    NSLog(@"Playing file at %@", fileURL);

    NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileURL withExtension:@"m4a"];


    // TESTING
    //url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"seconds" withExtension:@"m4a"];
    // END TESTING

    NSAssert(url, @"URL is invalid.");

    // create the player
    NSError* error = nil;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if(!player)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating player: %@", error);
    };

    [player play];

    [task success:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you post the method you're calling it in?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam I've edited my post as per your request :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForgeLog` and `NSLog` don't log to the web inspector console. When developing a plugin, this log output can be seen in XCode, when using a plugin as part of an app this output will appear in the Toolkit or commandline tool output.

If you want to make something appear in the web inspector from your plugin, you are probably best off communicating from native code to JavaScript data through an event: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/javascript_events.html and use `console.log` in the event listener.